# When it comes to pre-ŋ raising of /ɪ/ to /i/ in California English, does this raising universally affect all the words containing -ing?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

Like how king becomes /kiŋ/ and singing becomes /siŋiŋ/. But does this affect all words containing the -ing suffix? On top of my head, I can think of a word like building where I think this raising doesn't happen but I am not sure about that. It'd be good to have a set of rules that dictate how this works.

Comment: Notice that the song “Singin’ in the Rain” has /siŋɪn/for its first word. And it's probably unfair to blame all this on the Californians, since it’s really part of the tense/lax neutralization that we see before rhotics and nasals that accounts for why words like *rang, range, marry* all have /e/ in them never /æ/ in most American English dialects, and why *orange* has two tense vowels in it for us and no lax ones.  Notice also that we have no native words ending in *-eng* in English. All the same thing.

Comment: Can you corroborate the claim that the /ɪ/ doesn't raise to [i] before /ŋ/ in *building* in Californian accent (or any other accent that has the raising)? The raising is conditioned by the following velar nasal so it should equally raise all the preceding /ɪ/s.

Comment: @tchrist, is it really the same vowel in *rang* and *range*? I'd expect most Americans pronounce them differently.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul There is only one /ŋ/ in *Singin’* from the song.

Comment: @ThePhoton What else would they say? *Rang* and *range* and *rain* and *rare*  and *rate* all have the same /e/ vowel where I’m from in the Upper Midwest / Inland North. For the /æ/ vowel you need *ran* or *Randy*, and for the /ɛ/ vowel you need *wrench* or *wren*.

Comment: @tchrist as a northern Californian, for me *range* has (I'm pretty sure) the same vowel as *rage*. *Rang* has the same vowel as *rag*.

Comment: @ThePhoton I quite assure you that folks where I'm from say *range* exactly the same way they say *rain* except they add an extra affricate at the end, that same one that occurs twice in *judge*: the vowel is identical in both. Try it yourself: ***a rain jester, arrange ester, a range ester*** should all be the same. Are you representing that you yourself say the word *ran* and then add the affricate to make *range*? That’s challenging for me to imagine, for I question whether I could distinguish that from a voiced version of *wrench*.

Comment: @tchrist, No, I agree that *rain* and *range* have the same vowel. I'm saying *rang* has a different vowel. The word you'd get by tacking a "g" on the end of "rain" I'd spell as "wreng".

Comment: @ThePhoton No native English words end in *-eng*. Consider why not.

Comment: @tchrist, that was meant as a joke, meaning there isn't any such word. I still think that in California *rang* and *range* have different vowels. (But I'm willing to be educated by someone who knows more about how different two sounds have to be to be called different)